# What is the application order of transforms for QML Item?

Tags: qml, affinetransform

A QML `Item` may have several transforms in several forms:
translation via `x` and `y` properties, rotaion via `rotation` properties group, scaling via `scale` properties group, and finally it has the `transform` property which contains a list of transformations to apply.

Clearly the transformations in the `transform` list are applied in order as they are declared.
But what is the order of the rest of transforms, will rotation be applied first or scale? and the translation will be applied after both of them? and if the `transform` list is specified will it be applied before or after other transformations have been applied?

Comment: This could be of interest https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp.html#_ZNK17QQuickItemPrivate21itemToParentTransformER10QTransform

Comment: The `rotation` and `scale` origins are based on the item's center, so it does not matter which one comes first. However, the transformations of the `scale` and `rotation` properties come before the `transform` property list.

Answer (score 0):

QML has built-in smarts for inferring the origin of the transformations, so, often, you don't have to do anything, for instance, in the following, the 40x40 red `Rectangle` will rotate and scale and stay centered inside the 200x200 orange `Rectangle`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200; height: 200
        color: "orange"
        Rectangle {
            x: 80; y: 80; width: 40; height: 40
            color: "red"
            rotation: rot.value
            scale: sc.value
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        Slider { id: rot; from: 0; to: 360 }
        Slider { id: sc; from: 0.5; to: 5.0; value: 1 }
    }
}
```

This means, most often, you should have no need to set `transform` and rely that `rotation` and `scale` will do the job for you.

In some cases, you may want to intentionally move and manipulate the origin of your `rotation` and `scale`. You can do this by introducing a placeholder `Item` and assigning the `rotation` and `scale` to different elements:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200; height: 200
        color: "orange"
        Item {
            x: 100 + 10
            y: 100 + 10
            Rectangle {
                x: -20 - 10; y: -20 - 10; width: 40; height: 40
                color: "red"
                rotation: rot.value
            }
            scale: sc.value
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        Slider { id: rot; from: 0; to: 360 }
        Slider { id: sc; from: 0.5; to: 5.0; value: 1 }
    }
}
```